# Is something wrong with my proposed proof of the sequential continuity of probability?

Tags: probability, solution-verification

The proof I came up with is different from what I found everywhere else so I'm trying to find my error.

Given a probability triple $(\Omega,P,\mathcal{U})$ and the events $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq A_3 \subseteq A_4 \ldots $ show that:

$$ P( \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n ) = \lim_{m \to \infty} P(A_m)$$

The proofs I've come across consider disjoint sets and use the axiom of additivity. These are fine but I came up with something else:

If $A_1 \subseteq A_2 $ then $ A_1 \cup A_2 = A_2 $. Hence,

$$ P( \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n ) = P( \lim_{m \to \infty} A_m) = \lim_{m \to \infty} P(A_m)$$

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you define $\lim A_m$? How do you know that you can interchange $P$ with $\lim$? Well, that actually is the content of the statement that you want to prove.

Comment: I guess that's my problem: I don't understand how the two sides of the last equality (where I move the limit) could be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof you have is probably like this:

Let
$$
B_1=A_1,\quad B_m=A_m\setminus A_{m-1},\quad m>1
$$

Then you have a disjoint union $\cup B_m$ which is equal to $\cup A_m$.

Now you have
$$
P(\cup A_m)=P(\cup B_m)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^N P(B_m)=
\lim_{N\to\infty}P(A_N)
$$

---

As user251257 pointed out in the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3989278/is-something-wrong-with-my-proposed-proof-of-the-sequential-continuity-of-probab/3989284#comment8232410_3989278), you need to define $\lim_{m\to\infty} A_m$. But it is usually defined that
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty} A_m:=\cup_{m=1}^\infty A_m
$$
for $A_1\subset A_2\subset \cdots$.

You are using what you are supposed to prove.

---

In general,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n:=\cap_{n=1}^\infty\cup_{m\ge n} A_m,\quad
\liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n:=\cup_{n=1}^\infty\cap_{m\ge n} A_m,\quad
$$